# Changing Mysql values in row when displayed

Tags: mysql

I  have a table`entities` .In this table I got columns :`Rank Name Spouse Level Online Class` as seen when displayed in site >>Class in the table is  numbers values like 25 . 145 ....  I want the following message to be displayed like :`number 25 displayed as Good`. `number 145 displayed as Verygood` .

see this 
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E2eK.png

Comment: please paste the same query did u use

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
CASE Class 
WHEN 25 THEN 'good'
WHEN 145 THEN 'very good'
END AS translatedNumbers
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something similar:

```
SELECT name,
       IF(class=25,"Good",IF(class(145,"Verygood",class)) AS display 
FROM yourtable
```

Or you can use `case`:

```
SELECT name,
     CASE class 
         WHEN 25 THEN "Good" 
         WHEN 125 THEN "Verygood"
         ELSE class 
     END AS display 
FROM yourtable
```

Read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)!